# Angular app gives 404 error while refreshing any page

Tags: angular

My angular app gives 404 error after refreshing any page. Although app works fine while running from local, it only happens in production. My angular version is 16. And app url is something like this: https://app.abc.xyz/dashboard

[image]

Comment: what are you using as a server that serves your angular application in production

Answer (score 1):

When running locally, the dev server rewrite every url to index.html, thus allowing the angular router to handle the route.
When deploying in production you need to setup this rewriting yourself, otherwise the server tries to serve something like dashboard.html which does not exists, as angular is an SPA framework.
The server should only server the index.html for any request and the angular router should then render the appropriate page.

For information about rewriting take a look at this: https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration
Theres instructions for most popular web-servers.
In nginx it might looks like this: `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;`
Any uri will be rewritten to index.html.